# Routing Error uninitialized constant SubmitsController (Trying to upload document using Carrierwave)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-3, carrierwave

I am building my first useful Rails application for a teacher to post assignments and students to upload their work (jpeg|pdf) on the website using Carrierwave.

Tutorial I want to replicate: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby-on-rails/rails-file-uploading.htm

Error: *"`undefined method submits_path' for #<#:0x007f7260dbc7a0> Did you mean? submit_path"*

Error message: *Extracted source (around line #14):*

```
13    <div class = "well">
14       <%= form_for @submits, html: { multipart: true } do |f| %>
15          <%= f.label :name %>
16          <%= f.text_field :name %>
17          <%= f.label :attachment %>
```

model: submit.rb

```
class Submit < ActiveRecord::Base
    mount_uploader :attachment, AttachmentUploader # Tells rails to use this uploader for this model.
   validates :name, presence: true # Make sure the owner's name is present.
end
```

controller: submit_controller.rb

```
class SubmitController < ApplicationController
 def index
      @submits = Submit.all
 end

   def new
      @submit = Submit.new
   end

   def create
      @submit = Submit.new(submit_params)

      if @submit.save
         redirect_to submits_path, notice: "The assignment #{@submit.name} has been uploaded."
      else
         render "new"
      end

   end

   def destroy
      @submit = Submit.find(params[:id])
      @submit.destroy
      redirect_to submits_path, notice:  "The assignment #{@submit.name} has been deleted."
   end

   private
      def submit_params
      params.require(:submit).permit(:name, :attachment)
      end

end
```

routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

resources :submit, only: [:index, :new, :create, :destroy]

  get 'welcome/index'

  get 'welcome/about'

  root 'welcome#index'
end
```

schema:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20160903040246) do

  create_table "submits", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "attachment"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

end
```

`rake routes` :

```
       Prefix Verb   URI Pattern              Controller#Action
 submit_index GET    /submit(.:format)        submit#index
              POST   /submit(.:format)        submit#create
   new_submit GET    /submit/new(.:format)    submit#new
       submit DELETE /submit/:id(.:format)    submit#destroy
welcome_index GET    /welcome/index(.:format) welcome#index
welcome_about GET    /welcome/about(.:format) welcome#about
         root GET    /                        welcome#index
```

Thanks in advance to all the wonderful people here who are willing to lend a helping hand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using `@submits` insted of `@submit`, here:

```
<%= form_for @submits, html: { multipart: true } do |f| %>
```

Shoul be:

```
<%= form_for @submit, html: { multipart: true } do |f| %>
```

Which is the variable you have created in the controller, here:

```
def new
  @submit = Submit.new
end
```

**EDITED ANSWER**

I'm gonna take a step back here and point some problems you're facing due to Rails Convention.

The Rails philosophy is Convention Over Configuration. That means that if you follow some conventions, Rails will be able to do what you expect it to do it without configuring anything (or almost anything).

Besides the error I pointed above, all the other errors you have listed in the answers are because you created your controller in the singular `SubmitController` instead of `SubmitsController`. This changes the convention expected by Rails, so you would have to some configurations by hand.

Since you're following a tutorial or something, my advice is to take a step back and re-create your controller with the right conventions.

Comment: thanks for the quick response appreciate it, now im getting `undefined method `submits_path' for #<#<Class:0x007f726112cb88>:0x007f7260dbc7a0>
Did you mean?  submit_path` for the same line of code

Comment: Can you show the code? You can check the routes aliases that exist running `rake routes` in the root path of your app.

Comment: `Prefix Verb   URI Pattern              Controller#Action
 submit_index GET    /submit(.:format)        submit#index
              POST   /submit(.:format)        submit#create
   new_submit GET    /submit/new(.:format)    submit#new
       submit DELETE /submit/:id(.:format)    submit#destroy
welcome_index GET    /welcome/index(.:format) welcome#index
welcome_about GET    /welcome/about(.:format) welcome#about
         root GET    /                        welcome#index`

Comment: now I am getting a 'Routing Error uninitialized constant SubmitsController'

Comment: Ok. I'm gonna say now to you take a step back and try to study a little about rails conventions. 

What may have happened is that when you created your controller, you created it with the resource name in the singular. Rails convention say to use it in the plural, and that's when the 'magical' things happens.

Comment: Since you're used in the singular, by the output in your `rake routes`, you can let the `resources :submit` as it was, and use `submit_index_path` instead of `submits_path`.

Comment: But then, later you'll run into other problems, because rails expect a certain convention (The convention over configuration philosofy).

Comment: OH yes i just realized my controllers name is "submit_controller" instead of submit(s)_controller, I forgot about this when I generated the controller. Thank you for the help!